# A simple Code but still wrong - assignment of function 'void pinMode(uint8_t, uint8_t)'

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Just to power a LED.

```
void setup() {

 pinMode=(5, OUTPUT);
}

 void loop() {

 digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
 delay(5000);
 digitalWrite(5, LOW);
 delay(5000);
 }
```

But still not working...

> `Error: assignment of function 'void pinMode(uint8_t, uint8_t)'`

Please don't laugh at me but I just can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The error message:

> "*Error: assignment of function 'void pinMode(uint8_t, uint8_t)'*"

describes that you attempt to assign a value to a function - which is something different than a passed argument.

---

This is caused by the following:

There is a `=` between the the function identifier `pinMode` and its argument list:

```
pinMode=(5, OUTPUT);
```

The correct call to the function `pinMode()` is:

```
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
```

Comment: questions with typo in code are off-topic. please don't answer questions like this

Comment: @Juraj: In general that's true, but this typo or brain fart produced a recognizable error message `Error: assignment of function` that people with the same typo can usefully google on and find this.  If the question isn't a duplicate, this is a good answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, but then I read the answer and it didn't explain the error message

Comment: @Juraj Here you got the requested error explanation.